# FuelUX Wizard is not submitting my form when click on 'finished'

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, fuelux

I'm using bootstrap and FuelUX (just the Wizard). I use the wizard with a Form, and want to submit the Form (via jquery) when the user is at the last step and clicks "Finish". But everything in my "Finish"-Handler works, but not the `.submit` part. What am I doing wrong?

My code looks like:

```
<form id="wizard_form" ...>
<input ... />
</form>

$('#fuelux_wizard').on('finished', function(e, data) {
    $("#wizard_form").submit();
    console.log("OK");
});
```

When I do the same with a normal button displayed anywhere... it works.

Comment: Any errors showing up in your console?  It may be helpful if you would show the rest of your form markup and/or post an example somewhere like http://www.bootply.com/ - you'll find Fuel UX under "More Includes"

Comment: No, no errors at all. But I made it now "quick and dirty" and make a `$("submit button").click();` when the user clicks 'finish' at the wizard.

Answer (score 4):

I landed on this when my form, with a button of type submit, in a Fuel UX wizard wouldn't actually trigger a submit

Checkout my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/caDka/1) which seems to work

```
var wizard = $(".wizard").wizard();
wizard.on('finished', function (e, data) {
    $("#form-in-wizard").submit();
    console.log("submitted!");
});
```